# Зачем делать родительский класс абстрактным?

Tags: c++, ооп, абстрактная-фабрика

Вот у меня есть класс `Enemy`, в нём есть различные методы и свойства. От него я уже буду наследовать всяких волков, гоблинов и т.п. А зачем делать класс `Enemy` абстрактным и, соответственно, запрещать создавать его экземпляры?

P.S. Я понимаю зачем нужны базовые классы, но зачем делать их абстрактными с помощью *pure virtual* функций?

Comment: чтобы нельзя было их напрямую инициализировать, например))

Comment: А как вы хотите использовать экземпляр Enemy?

Comment: А вы случайно не путаете причину и следствие?

Comment: @Unick я и не хочу, просто спрашиваю, в чём смысл делать его абстрактным, просто "правило хорошего тона"?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Если вы не хотите никогда создавать класс Enemy, то зачем ему не абстрактные методы? Следовательно избавляемся от них и да это также "правило хорошего тона". Но иногда базовые классы имеют неабстрактые методы если это предотвратит дублирование. Но если вы экспортируете его из dll например, то лучше делать абстрактным.

Answer (score 9):

Вам нужно нарисовать врага. Вы добавляете в класс метод `draw()`. Но что рисовать Вы не знаете. Знать будет конкретный наследник. Поэтому вы объявляете метод `draw()` абстрактным

Тогда Вы в этом классе можете определить перемещение

```
void move(int newPosition) {
  draw(false);  // скрываем объект
  setPosition(newPosition);  // будем рисовать в новой позиции
  draw(true);  // рисуем в новом месте
}
```

Тогда класс Enemy будет уметь перемещать любого своего потомка. При этом сам метод `move` переопределять у потомков не нужно

Comment: Да это-то понятно, но почему бы просто не сделать draw() {}? Делать класс абстрактным нужно просто для понятности, что его использовать не стоит и нет смысла?

Comment: @МишаковМаксим Расширил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Абстрактные классы используются в качестве интерфейсов. С помощью абстрактных классов в языке реализуется полиморфизм.